# When do you say software/package is successfully installed?

Tags: macos, shell, ubuntu, xampp, sudo

I am installing Xampp server on ubuntu.

```
sudo ./xampp-installer.run
```

Above command definitely installs the xampp, but it's interactive mode.

```
sudo ./xampp-installer.run --mode unattended
```

Above command also installs the xampp without interactive mode. This is what i wanted. It doesn't print any console logs.

How to say/verify, as the installation is successful ?

Comment: If any error occurs, it will show up. To verify it, check the logs

Comment: No, in "--mode unattended" scenario , it does not show any logs.

Comment: I mean log files, somewhere /var/xamp...